# May a woman eat on the street?

Tags: women, eating, edim-witnesses

According to Kiddushin 40b, one who eats on the street cannot serve as a witness.

Since women anyway cannot serve as witness, is it allowed for them to eat on the street? Is there some discussion about it in the poskim?

Comment: Women can serve as witnesses in some contexts. And why do you think it's prohibited for a man to eat in the street if he doesn't want to be a witness?

Comment: Rashi explains that the reason he can’t be a witness is due to his lack of basic dignity. A woman should be even more careful about that, surely not less. https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Kiddushin.40b.13.1?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: The Gemara says one who eats on the street is similar to a dog. Call me old-fashioned, but I think woman should have higher standards than behaving like dogs.

Comment: This question confuses one *consequence* of eating on the street, and construes it as a *reason*. Not being a valid witness isn't the *reason* for not eating on the street, it is just an *effect*.

Comment: @N.T.: the Gemara says right afterwards that the halacha follows the opinion that says that the only ‏implication is that (s)he is not a valid witness. We don't pasken that one is likened to a dog and no separate prohibition is apparent either.

Comment: @Esther: as above, the Gemara in the next line excludes the idea that there is anything else (reason or prohibition) besides pasul eidus.